# Oracle pipelined table function in JPQL

Tags: oracle, jpql, pipelined-function

is there the possibility to include oracle pipelined table function in JPQL query.
I tried this

```
SELECT
   e,
   FUNC.DATE
FROM
   TABLE(MYFUNCTION(:id)) FUNC,
   MyClass e
WHERE
   FUNC.ID = e.id
```

but I have following error:

```
unexpected token: TABLE: line 1:58: unexpected token: TABLE
```

Comment: JPQL is not SQL. It never uses tables and column names. Always mapped entities and their fields/properties.

Comment: You could create a view that selects from the pipelined table function, map it to JPQL and use it there I suppose.